# Represent the interval [0,1) by union

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I can represent the set $(0,1]$ like: 
$(0,1] = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} (0, \frac{n+1}{n}) = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} [\frac{1}{n},1]$.

But how can I represent $[0,1)$? I have a task, which requires this of me.

$[0,1) = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{-1}{n},1) = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} [0, \frac{1}{n}]$.

Is this $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} [0, \frac{1}{n}]$ correct form?

Comment: I'm guessing that instead of explicitly writing infinity, you would take the limit. Otherwise, I'm pretty sure that or any other set with limiting point 0 would work

Comment: @Arsenii: As regards your terminology, the intervals in question are closed at one endpoint and open at the other, but they are neither open nor closed. The term _clopen_ means a set which is _both_ open and closed.

Comment: @quasi You right, I was wrong in English terms, yes. I meant exactly that they are neither open nor closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your representation of $[0,1)$ as the intersection of open sets is correct, but not that as the union of closed sets. This can be obtained by "reversing" the corresponding representation of $(0,1]$:
$$\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\left[0,\frac{n-1}n\right]$$

Comment: Maybe you know some similar tasks so that I can work on them finding such equations?

Comment: @Arsenii What I present here can be easily generalised to handle arbitrary open ends and isolated points when dealing with unions of closed intervals.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} [0, \frac{1}{n}]$ means something like this:

$$ [0, \tfrac{1}{1}] \cup [0, \tfrac{1}{2}] \cup [0, \tfrac{1}{3}] \cup \cdots$$

where the "$\cdots$" represents the limit as we take unions of more sets of the form 
$[0, \frac{1}{n}]$ on the right side of the expression.

Since $[0, \frac{1}{n}] \subseteq [0, \frac{1}{1}]$ whenever $n \geq 1,$
the union comes out to simply $[0, \tfrac{1}{1}].$
This has $1$ as an element, which is not what you want.

Starting at a larger value of $n$ doesn't help; it eliminates $1$ but also eliminates many elements you want to include, such as $\frac34.$

Here's an alternative idea: instead of having the right-hand end of the interval start at some positive value and approach $0$, have it approach the open end of the desired set instead; that is, have it approach $1.$

Comment: I understand all of your answer, but the only one point: what do you mean, when said that "this has $1$ as an element, which is not you want"? That mean, that I must have the $1$ like a limit point?

Comment: The interval $[0,1)$ is a set of numbers including $0$ and all the numbers strictly between $0$ and $1.$ The number $1$ is a limit point of that set, as you say, but it is not an element of the set.